# Average number of steps on a graph from node A to node B.

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory

For a given undirected graph, if you have a 'person' that is able to move randomly from node to node only along edges, and, at each node, for a given time-step, if that node has N edges, the person will have a probability of 1/N of moving along each edge connected to that node, what is the average number of time-steps for a path that starts at A and ends at B? Is there a formula for finding this based on the edges in the graph?

Comment: This can be modeled as an [absorbing Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorbing_Markov_chain) by making node B the only absorbing state.

Comment: Thank you. This is precisely what i was looking for. However, looking into absorbing Markov chains it seems this can only be used for finding the average number of time-steps for a path from A to B where A is not equal to B. Is there some variation on absorbing Markov chains which allows one to find the average number of steps going from A to itself?

Comment: I figured it out. Can use the same process for all neighboring nodes (+1 for the step to that node) and average the result. Nice clean answers. Thanks again.